# VS code Blurs out when mouse is not on it

Tags: visual-studio-code, blur

[image: VS Code is blurry]

I have a 1070ti and my VS code used to run perfectly I fresh installed Windows and now VS code blurs out and can't see if my mouse moves away.
I have already tried turning off "Fix Apps that are blurry"
I have already tried adding it to NVIDIA settings, and I have no problems playing heavy rendering games. Only when I am coding and it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score -1):

i solved this problem , you should open nvidia and do restore